# Setting a proxy server for Paw requests

Tags: paw-app

I'm testing an API that requires me to connect to it through a proxy server (for IP whitelisting). How do I set this connection within Paw on Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure proxy settings in `Paw > Preferences > HTTP`. If you use Paw HTTP library and set `System Proxy Configuration` Paw will follow your system settings for HTTP Proxy. You can also set a special configuration for Paw if you choose `Custom Proxy Configuration`. 
For SOCKS Proxy switch to NSURLConnection and Paw will follow your system configuration.[image: proxy]